# How to modify content of the original variable which is passed by value?

Tags: c++, c, api, parameter-passing

There is an existing API function which does only allow the plugin(DLL) to receive three parameters and perform some action:

```
int ProcessMe(int nCommand, unsigned int wParam, long lParam);
```

Now, from the main program(exe), would like to pass two variables to the plugin, and require plugin to modify their content, and main program will read them again, to perform some task.

My question is, from the above function, can I perform this, without changing the function parameters?

Example:

```
int ProcessMe(int nCommand, unsigned int wParam, long lParam)
{
  // modify the parameters//
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  BOOL bSave = TRUE;
  int nOption = 0;
  ProcessMe(0, (unsigned int)(&bSave), (long)(&nOption));
  if(FALSE==bSave)
    printf("bSave is modified!");
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: No. You need to pass by reference, which you cannot do without changing the API. You'll either have to reimplement the interface with pointers, or learn to live without.

Comment: Sadly i'm not allowed to change the interface, as there are currently many other DLLs running with the exe using the similar interface.... backward compatibility concern for me :(

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The function won't be expecting to use the parameters to store results. They are not for output. You need to declare a new function.

Comment: Yes can be done: the parameters passed to your function are only passed by value, but the last argument can in fact be an address (passed by value) such that ProcessMe can manipulate the data at that address: in the calling program cast a pointer to long and vice versa in ProcessMe.

Comment: While passing a pointer as the lParam will work with care, (see all the other posts re. issues), you should note that the format of this call is suspiciously like Windows SendMessage/PostMessage.  If this call is a PostMessage wrapper, it is possible that the request made is not complete when the call returns and so any vars referenced in the call may not have been written yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the variables to modify in a struct and pass the pointer to the sturuct to the plug in:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    BOOL bSave;
    int nOption;
};

int ProcessMe(int nCommand, unsigned int wParam, long lParam)
{
    ((MyStruct*)lParam)->nOption = ...;
    return 0;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
int main()
{
  MyStruct struct;
  struct.bSave = TRUE;
  struct.nOption = 0;
  ProcessMe(0, 0, (long)(&struct));
  if(FALSE==struct.bSave)
    printf("bSave is modified!");
  return 1;
}
```

Strictly speaking this is undefined behavior. You need to check, whether it works on your platform.

Note: I used a struct here, because this way you can also pass more variables or larger variables such as double to the function.

Comment: Wrong, this won't modify the original parameters. `wParam` will still be the same.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - of course! The intent is to modify the contents of the struct.

Comment: What struct? There's no struct in his code. Your answer answers a whole different question.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: The author meant that the caller may pass a pointer to an arbitrary struct instead of the `lParam`

Comment: Casting pointers to integer types falls under implementation defined behavior.  It is undefined in this case if `long` happens to not be sufficiently large enough to hold the pointer value after conversion.

Comment: @jamesdlin: As an exception to the "implementation-defined" part, roundtripping is guaranteed by the Standard if the integral type is large enough.  Most likely `long` is a typo, all the WinAPI functions with parameters named `lParam` actually use a pointer-sized integer for that.

Answer (score 3):

**No, there's no way to do that.**

Passing by value means copies of the original ones are created. In the method scope, you will have no information about the original variables.

You need to either pass by reference or by value.

Comment: This is not correct. Although you cannot do it in a type-safe way, you can do it by reinterpreting the contents of the `lParam`. This in fact happens a lot in Win32 API. Henrik has already shown a solution that works.

Comment: @AlefSin dereferencing NULL pointers also happens in Win32 API. That's why we have a standard to guide us, not the MSDN documentation.

Comment: I know it is not type-safe, and I said that. This all stems from the fact that some older API were designed in an era when C programmers didn't care much about type-safety. When you cannot change the code of the API, you'll have to resort to an ugly, unsafe, non-portable and possibly dangerous solution anyway.

Comment: +1 for AlefSin ' ugly, unsafe, non-portable and possibly dangerous' maybe, but also, as in the case of kernel API, often 'unavoidable'.  Unavoidable wins.

Comment: @AlefSin: Roundtripping through an integer of sufficient size is guaranteed by the Standard.  If you have to do it with an integer of insufficient size, using an index to a global array of pointers can work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... it is POSSIBLE!!!

## include

int ProcessMe(int nCommand, unsigned int wParam, long lParam)

{

```
int *nCommand_ptr = (int*)nCommand;
unsigned int *wParam_ptr = (unsigned int*)wParam;
long *lParam_ptr = (long*)lParam;
*nCommand_ptr = 10;
*wParam_ptr = 10;
*lParam_ptr = 10;
return 0;
```

}

int main(){

```
int nCommand = 5;
unsigned int wParam = 5;
long lParam = 5;
printf("\n %d %u %lu",nCommand,wParam,lParam);
ProcessMe((int)&nCommand,(unsigned int)&wParam,(long)&lParam);
printf("\n %d %u %lu",nCommand,wParam,lParam);
return 0;
```

}

Output:

$>g++ passbyref.cc

$>./a.out

5 5 5

10 10 10$>

Answer (score 1):

Compiling for 32 bits platform you could cast to pointer the parameter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int BOOL;
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

int ProcessMe(int nCommand, unsigned int wParam, long lParam)
{
  // cast to match what you passed in
  *((BOOL*)wParam) = FALSE;
  return 0;
}

int cast_arguments_main(int, char **)
{
  BOOL bSave = TRUE;
  int nOption = 0;
  ProcessMe(0, (unsigned int)(&bSave), (long)(&nOption));
  if(FALSE==bSave)
    printf("bSave is modified!");
  return 1;
}
```

On a 64 bits platform the compiler complains about the impossibility to represent the pointer:

```
cast_arguments.cpp:17:37: error: cast from ‘BOOL*’ to ‘unsigned int’ loses precision
```

I had to change the `unsigned int wParam` parameter declaration to `unsigned long wParam`, and similar change at call point: `ProcessMe(0, (unsigned long)(&bSave), (long)(&nOption));`
but then you could simply declare the right type for your parameter, to be `BOOL *`. Thus feasibility depends on your target machine architecture...

Comment: On 64-bit Windows (which is where the name `lParam` pops up the most), the type of lParam isn't `long`.  Actually he probably should just be using `intptr_t` to begin with.