# Why doesn't return modify the value of a parameter to a function

Tags: c, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify content of the original variable which is passed by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938096/how-to-modify-content-of-the-original-variable-which-is-passed-by-value)

I am building a pretty simple program that calculates the area of a rectangle. Simple enough however, as you will notice I cannot seem to get a return value. I keep seeing 0. There is probably an obvious answer or perhaps there is something I just don't understand. Heres my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

//prototypes
int FindArea(int , int , int);

main()
{

//Area of a Rectangle

  int rBase,rHeight,rArea = 0;

  //get base
  printf("\n\n\tThis program will calculate the Area of a rectangle.");
  printf("\n\n\tFirst, enter a value of the base of a rectangle:");
  scanf(" %d" , &rBase);

  //refresh and get height
  system("cls");
  printf("\n\n\tNow please enter the height of the same rectangle:");
  scanf(" %d" , &rHeight);

  //refresh and show output
  system("cls");
  FindArea (rArea , rBase , rHeight);
  printf("\n\n\tThe area of this rectangle is %d" , rArea);
  getch();

}//end main

int FindArea (rArea , rBase , rHeight)
{
 rArea = (rBase * rHeight);

 return (rArea);

}//end FindArea
```

Comment: You assign `rArea = 0` at the top, which is why it always returns 0.

Comment: If you don't have a clue about this, you hadn't read a basic C tutorial attentively enough. -1.

Comment: Yes I have. The example was unrelated to what I am doing, using (void) or in other words no return value. Another used addition and my prof doesn't speak English audibly. I used a different method of declaring variables this time in a rush just experimenting with a faster way than initializing them individually. That was irrelevant to the problem however, I appreciate your feedback but insulting me is also irrelevant to what I did wrong. This was my first attempt at a function that I created and obviously misunderstood the concept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify content of the original variable which is passed by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938096/how-to-modify-content-of-the-original-variable-which-is-passed-by-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You intialize `rArea` to 0. Then, you pass it into `FindArea` **by value**. This means none of the changes to `rArea` in the function are reflected. You don't make use of the return value, either. Therefore, `rArea` stays 0.

Option 1 - Use the return value:

```
int FindArea(int rBase, int rHeight) {
    return rBase * rHeight;
}

rArea = FindArea(rBase, rHeight);
```

Option 2 - Pass by reference:

```
void FindArea(int *rArea, int rBase, int rHeight) {
    *rArea = rBase * rHeight;
}

FindArea(&rArea, rBase, rHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not storing the return value. The code won't compile in its present form.

1. Call it as:

   ```
   rArea = (rBase , rHeight);
   ```
2. Change the function to:

   ```
   int FindArea (int rBase ,int rHeight)  
   {  
       return (rBase * rHeight);  
   }
   ```
3. Change the prototype to:

   ```
   int FindArea(int , int);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the return value of `FindArea` to `rArea`. At the moment, `FindArea` assigns the product to *its* local variable of the same name.

Alternatively, you can pass the address of `main`'s `rArea` to modify that, that would look like

```
FindArea(&rArea, rBase, rHeight);
```

in `main` with

```
void FindArea(int * rArea, int rBase, int rHeight) {
    *rArea = rBase * rHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FindArea (rArea , rBase , rHeight);
```

doesn't work like you think it does. In C, parameters are passed by value; that means modifying `area` inside the function modifies only a local copy of it. You need to assign the return value of the function to the variable:

```
int FindArea(int w, int h) { return w * h; }

int w, h, area;

// ...
area = findArea(w, h);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you never assign another value than 0 to rArea in your main program.

Answer (score 0):

take `rArea` by pointer:

```
int FindArea(int *, int , int);

...

FindArea (&rArea , rBase , rHeight);

...



int FindArea (int *rArea , int rBase , int rHeight)
{
 *rArea = (rBase * rHeight);

 return (*rArea);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is you don't understand how to get values out of a function.  Change the relevant lines to:

```
int FindArea(int rBase, int rHeight);  // prototype
```

and

```
int area = FindArea(rBase, rHeight);
```

and

```
int FindArea(int rBase, int rHeight)
{
     return rBase * rHeight;
}
```