# Incrementing integer in a function in C

Tags: c

I have this very simple program

```
int test(int asdf){
  asdf = asdf + 1;
  return 0;
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv ){

  int a = 1;
  test(a);
  printf("a is %d\n", a);
}
```

I want the program to output 2, but instead it outputs 1. What went wrong? How should I pass the reference?

Comment: @RaymondChen: Beware, the accepted answer to that question is nonsense.

Comment: @Keith: No, it's quite good, for solving a very different problem (how do I share an object with my callback function?).  It simply isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Rats. I got it from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699712/why-doesnt-return-modify-the-value-of-a-parameter-to-a-function) which is a closer match to the question.

Comment: That's ok vote to close (because it has been answered already) but why all these downvotes rather just point to duplicate topic?

Comment: @Raymond: Yes, that one is a good duplicate.  It doesn't have all the type erasure baggage, just gets to the point of transferring a result from function to caller.

Comment: @Jack I didn't downvote, but my guess is that the question has many duplicates, so the OP did not do sufficient research before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get started with a Pointers chapter from good C book

```
int test(int* asdf){   // Argument will be pointer to integer
  *asdf = *asdf + 1;   // de-reference and access asdf's content & increment
  return 0;
}

test(&a); // Pass address of a
```

Comment: This doesn't help a student, because it doesn't even try to explain the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you pass is going to get copied... so you should pass something, that even when copied, lets you find the original `a`.

That something is a pointer, and its value is the address of `a`.

If you write your friend's address on a piece of paper, then no matter how many times that paper gets copied, the person holding it can still find the original house.

You write a pointer as `int* asdf`, and the address of `a` is written as `&a`.  To find the object when you have a pointer, you need `*asdf`.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't support passing a variable by reference so you can't do that.

However, if you did pass a pointer to a variable then you could get the variable incremented.

Look at:

[Passing by reference in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229498/passing-by-reference-in-c)