# Void function: removing elements from an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to make a function that removes elements from an array.

I attempted making the function myself, however, not fully successful:

```
void remove_element(int* array, int number, int array_length)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < array_length; i++){
        if (array[i] == number) {
            for (j = i; j < array_length; j++)
                array[j] = array[j+1];
            array_length--;
        }
    }
}
```

first thing I noticed is after function is called in main, `array_lenght` is not changed, therefore length of an array remains the same after removing element(s).

So the first question is how to change length of an array inside the void function?

Second thing which doesn't work properly is if in an array are two or more same numbers next to each other, for example if array contains `1,1,3,4,5,6` and user wants to remove `1` function will remove only one element.

Example of my output (wrong):

```
1,1,3,4,5,6 after fucntion 1,3,4,5,6
```

Thanks

Comment: `array_length` is local to `remove_element`. However you manipulate that inside the function won't be visible outside of it. You'll need to pass in a pointer to `array_length` if you want its manipulation to persist beyond the scope of the function.

Comment: Also, this is unlikely to work... How is your array allocated? Please add more code...

Comment: for problem #2: `if(array[i]==number){` => `while(array[i]==number){`

Comment: Just for curiosity, you need to remove `1` from `1,1,3,4,5,6` because its a duplicate or is just a SPECIAL number?

Comment: `j<array_length` --> `j<array_length-1`

Comment: Thanks Jean-François Fabre, this fixed the problem #2, however, still length of the array is the problem, Michi, it was just an example why it didn't work, if I wanted to remove 3, array would be 1,1,4,5,6

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_pointers_to_functions.htm

Comment: BLUEPIXY, this does not work since if there are more than 1 element to be removed, length would still not be correct. Thanks yano, I will read this

Comment: `still length of the array is the problem`  ==>>> `size_t arrSize = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[o];`

Comment: You should consider to rethink about your program. You said `1,1,3,4,5,6 after function 1,3,4,5,6` Here you need to remove `1`, but which one should be, first `1` or the second `1` ? Your program should remove `1` because/after you know its Position or should find it with the help of your function?

Comment: Could use the return value as the array's new length: `array_length = remove_element(A, number, array_length);`  or pass by its address `remove_element(A, number, &array_length)`

Comment: It doesn't matter how many same numbers there are, in that case above if user wants to remove 1, all 1 's should be removed. that is fixed thanks to Jean-François Fabre, still can't get around the length...

Comment: `j<array_length --> j<array_length-1`. This doesn't fix a problem you see. This fixes a problem you don't see. When `j == array_length-1`, `array[j+1]` accesses `array[array_length]`, which is one too many.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't return modify the value of a parameter to a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699712/why-doesnt-return-modify-the-value-of-a-parameter-to-a-function)

Comment: @coolermaster Please check my Answer. You never said about how you declared your Array. Hope that Helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based now on your Comments, I'll do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void remove_element(int number, int *arr, size_t *size);

int main(void){
    int arr[] = {1,1,3,4,5,6};

    long unsigned int arrSize;
    int number = 1;
    arrSize = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];

    printf("Before:\n");
    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < arrSize ; i++ ){
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\nAfter:\n");
    remove_element( number, arr, &arrSize );

    for ( size_t j = 0 ; j < arrSize ; j++ ){
        printf("%d ", arr[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void remove_element(int number, int *arr, size_t *size){
    int arrTemp[*size];
    long unsigned int j = 0,c;

    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < *size ; i++ ){
        if ( arr[i] == number ){
                continue;
        }else{
            arrTemp[j] = arr[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    for ( size_t k = 0 ; k < j ; k++ ){
        arr[k] = arrTemp[k];
    }

    c = j;
    while ( *size > c ){
        arr[c] = 0;
        c++;
    }

    *size = j;
}
```

Output:

```
Before:
1 1 3 4 5 6 
After:
3 4 5 6
```

By the way in your Question you said:

```
Examples of output:

1,1,3,4,5,6 after fucntion 1,3,4,5,6
```

And in your Comment you said:

```
It doesn't matter how many same numbers there are, in that case above if user wants to remove 1, all 1 's should be removed.
```

Please make up your mind.

Comment: That was an example of my output, which was wrong, I edited it, I tested your code, modified it to my liking and it works, it is much more understandable than other codes. Thank you

Comment: @Coolermaster Please Accept my Answer if helped.

Answer (score 4):

In the current signature you cannot modify the array, as returning the new array you also need to return the new length.

There are many ways to do it, here is a way with a single loop:

```
void
remove_element(int* array, int number, int *array_length)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0, j=0; i < *array_length; i++) {
        if (array[i] != number)
            array[j++] = array[i];
    }
    *array_length = j;
}
```

Doing so, this will mutate both the initial array and the variable keeping its length in the caller and you must pass the value of array_length by reference, somthing like

```
int* some_array, some_array_length, n;

remove_element(some_array, n, &some_array_length)
```

Other method would be to return the new length and mutate the array or allocate a new array in the heap and return both the allocated array and the new length.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers to your question aside, if you're likely to do more than one removal on average (or more than one per call ever, actually), it's better not to shift all the subsequent values again and again. Try this:

```
void remove_element(int *array, int number, int *array_length) {
    for(int iRead = 0, iWrite = 0; iRead < *array_length; iRead++) {
        if(array[iRead] == number)
            continue; /* skip without increasing iWrite */
        if(iWrite < iRead) /* it works without this line, too, what's better depends */
            array[iWrite] = array[iRead];
        iWrite++;
    }
    *array_length = iWrite;
}
```

How this works, e.g., with `array = {1,1,2,2,3}` and `number = 2`:

```
1 1 2 2 3
^ iRead
^ iWrite
(increases both, writes nothing)

1 1 2 2 3
  ^ iRead
  ^ iWrite
(increases both, writes nothing)

1 1 2 2 3
    ^ iRead
    ^ iWrite
(continue happens: increases only iRead)

1 1 2 2 3
      ^ iRead
    ^ iWrite
(continue happens: increases only iRead)

1 1 2 2 3
        ^ iRead
    ^ iWrite
(writes 3 to iWrite, increases both)

1 1 3 2 3
          ^ iRead = 5
      ^ iWrite = 3
(iRead is no longer < *array_length, loop stops, 3 == iWrite is the new length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because array_length is not passed as pointer you're having copy of it on stack, so after you're getting outside of this function you're still having old value. You could use here memmove or memcpy instead of iteration over whole array after you find the same number. The reason why you didn't delete the next 1 in your array is, because when you're on  i = 0 -> array[0] == 1, but when you move all of the numbers back then you move second 1 to array[0], without checking it afterwards because after you finished iteration you just increment i, without checking if what you moved to current value of array[i] is the same as previous one.

```
void remove_element(int *array, int number, int *array_length){
    int sameValues = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < *array_length; i++){
        while(array[i] == number){
            *array_length--;
            sameValues++;
        }
        if(sameValues > 0){
            if(i < *array_length){
                memmove(&array[i], &array[i + sameValues], (*array_length - i) * sizeof(int));
            }
            sameValues = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

To make it even more dynamic you could use realloc (and actually resize the space occupied by your array after you remove members, but then either you need to return new pointer or you need to point to pointer on your stack from where you call the function:

```
void remove_element(int **array, int number, int *array_length){
    int sameValues = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < *array_length; i++){
        while((*array)[i] == number){
            *array_length--;
            sameValues++;
        }
        if(sameValues > 0){
            if(i < *array_length){
                memmove(&(*array)[i], &(*array)[i + sameValues], (*array_length - i) * sizeof(int));
            }
            realloc(*array, *array_length);
            sameValues = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. To use memmove you need to include string.h

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array the compiler will affect an amount of memory, and with array structure you can't change it. There is 2 solutions, change your `array length` but you still could access to the last "box" or redefine an array with the size wanted.
1st case :

```
void remove_element(int* array, int number, int * array_length){

int i = 0,j = 0;

while( i < *(array_length)-1){
    if(array[i] == number && !find){
        i++; //we step over
        find = 1; //we find 1 element stop remove
    }
    array[j] = array[i];
    i++;
    j++;   
}
*(array_length)--;
}
```

The `int * array_length` is a pointer to the memory, so your changes are keep when you go back in main. In your example, before `remove_element` array_length is equal to 6, and after it's 5. But you still could do array[5] (6th element cause notation 0 to 5 in c).

2nd case

```
int * remove_element(int * array, int number, int * array_length){

int * new_array = malloc((array_length -1) * sizeof(int)); // len - 1 cause we want to delet only 1 element

int i = 0;
int j = i;
int find = 0;
while( i < *(array_length)-1){
    if(array[i] == number && !find){
        i++; //we step over
        find = 1; //we find 1 element stop remove
    }
    new_array[j] = array[i];
    i++;
    j++;   
}
if (array[array_length] != number && !find){ //if we didn't find att all the element return array
    return array;
} else {
    *(array_length)--;
    return new_array;
}
}
```

Here you have to return the new_array because `int array[6]` in your main is a constant : you can't change it with `array = new_array`.

**Edit :** yes of course when you don't need anymore your array you have to free it with `free(array)` (or it's automatically done at the end of the processus, but it's not proper code)

There is also a shorter method with addtion of pointers but it seems quite too complicated with your c lvl :)

Comment: Here you need to remember to free array, otherwise you'll create memory leak.